# Seek how? (ἐκζητέω)

Tags: greek, word-study, translation-philosophy

Question for Greek scholars:
ἐκζητέω is translated

- “seek after” in Acts 15:17 & Romans 3:11;
- “Enquired” in I Peter 1:10;
- “Diligently seek” in Hebrews 11:6; and
- “Sought carefully” in Hebrews 12:17.

What justifies the adjectives in the last two instances, or their omission in the other three?

Comment: Which translation/version are you using ?

Comment: Ah, a familiar face! Welcome.

Comment: @NigelJ: those were KJV, but I consult several English, Spanish, and Italian.  They don’t all agree on the intensifiers.

Answer (score 1):

First, Heb 11:6 & 12:7 are not uniformly translated as "diligently seek" or "earnestly seek" (or something like that) by all versions.  ESV, NASB and CEV among other just translate this word as "seek".

"ekzeteo" comes from the root word "zeteo" meaning to seek.  "ekzeteo" has the added prefix "ek" meaning to seek out and represents a strengthened form of "zeteo".  According to BDAG, it means "to exert effort to find out or learn something".  According to the Analytical lexicon to the GNT (Friberg et al) it means, "of diligent investigation, scutenize … careful search for someone or something …".  So added adverbs "earnestly", "diligently" are entirely justified because it is not a casual search but an earnest search requiring effort.

A better question is: why in the other places this word occurs (eg, Acts 15:17 et al) such adverbs are NOT added?

Comment: Actually, that “better question” _was_ asked.  :-)  So εκ is an intensifier.  I didn’t know that.  Greek is not one of my languages.  Yet.

Comment: "EK" is NOT usually an intensifier - in this case it means to "seek out" but the net effect is to intensify the verb.

Answer (score 0):

As Wilke wrote on ἐκ (translated by Thayer),<sup>1</sup>

> VI. In COMPOSITION<sup>2</sup> ἐκ denotes
>   1. egress: ἐκβαίνω, ἐξέρχομαι.
>   2. emission, removal, separation: ἐκβάλλω, ἐκπέμπω, ἐξαιρέω.
>   3. origin: ἔκγονος.
>   4. publicity: ἐξαγγέλλω.
>   5. the unfolding, opening out, of something tied together or rolled up: ἐκτείνω, ἐκπετάννυμι.
>   6. is i. q. **utterly, entirely**, παντελῶς, [cf. Eng. out and out], **denoting completion and perfection**: ἐκπληρόω, ἐκτελέω. Cf. Fritzsche on Matt. p. 120 sq.

Hence, “diligently seek” would be an appropriate translation. It means to seek with the utmost effort and diligence.

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Wilke, p. [192](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q&f=true), ἐκ, VI., 6.
<sup>2</sup> Here, “composition” means “The combination, according to certain rules or principles, of two (or more) words to form one compound word.” (*OED* online)

### References

Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889.